# Google Maps disable directions and display map directly

Tags: html, google-maps, map-directions

I have searched on the internet to find out solution to this issue but i found nothing.

I have following address:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=2755+Maple+Avenue,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&daddr=2755+Maple+Ave,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&hnear=0x89c27ef151e2fa7d:0x2fde552872337fca,2755+Maple+Ave,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&gl=us&t=h&z=16


<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?source=embed&amp;q=2755+Maple+Avenue,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&amp;daddr=2755+Maple+Ave,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&amp;oe=utf-8&amp;client=firefox-a&amp;channel=fflb&amp;hnear=0x89c27ef151e2fa7d:0x2fde552872337fca,2755+Maple+Ave,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&amp;gl=us&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.684429,-73.529315&amp;spn=0.004881,0.013733&amp;z=16&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;oi=map_misc&amp;ct=api_logo" target="_blank" title="">open in new window</a>
```

When i click on above link in a mobile browser it opens a new page but instead of mapview it shows me directions panel, any one guide me how can i get rid of directions and display only mapview directly?

i have found a parameter dir=0 but i dont know where to use it.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=2755+Maple+Ave,+North+Bellmore,+NY+11710&hl=en&sll=40.684429,-73.529315&sspn=0.010983,0.026157&t=h&gl=us&hnear=2755+Maple+Ave,+North+Bellmore,+New+York+11710&z=16
```

use this in your map may be its helpful for you

Comment: but when i refresh it start displaying directions again.. :(